# Using ::before and ::after with multiple paragraphs for a "Proof" environment

Tags: html, css

Suppose I want to implement a *Proof* environment in HTML/CSS like the one that you commonly see in mathematical writing. Here is an example of what I mean typeset in LaTeX.

[image]

The key features are that the first paragraph starts with the word "*Proof*", and the last paragraph ends with a right-aligned square (tombstone). How could you write the CSS to implement this on a webpage? My best attempt at writing the CSS for this is:

```
p.proof {display: block;}
p.proof::before {content: "Proof. \00A0"; font-style: italic;}
p.proof::after {content: "\2610"; float:right;}
```

But this only works if a proof is a single paragraph, all inside of a single `<p class="proof">...<\p>`, and wouldn't work for the above example. I would really like to avoid having to specify the first and last paragraphs of a proof manually in the HTML. So ideally I'd like the HTML to look something like

```
<div class="proof">
  <p>This paragraph will have an italic "Proof" before it.</p>
  <p>Whereas this paragraph will have a square after it.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the paragraphs wrapped in some sort of external wrapper? You should really edit your question to include a HTML portion with this as well.

Comment: Using your code I created this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/L09z7f5t/) and it does  work. But as @disinfor mentioned, you will need to add your HTML to give a better idea of how the paragraphs are structured.

Comment: @disinfor No I wasn't including them in any sort of wrapper. But yeah, a reasonable solution to this would need to. I'll edit my question to include some "ideal" HTML for this.

Comment: @imvain2 Yeah, that's a way to get the desired effect, using `<br>` to manually create paragraph breaks in the middle of  a single `<p class="proof"> ... </p>`. But isn't this poor design? I'd prefer something more like the HTML at the end of my (edited) question, where I can have multiple paragraphs inside of a single "Proof" `<div>`.

Comment: Not sure why the accepted answer suggest `last-of-type` when there is `last-child`, which combined with `first-child` solves it. The `*-of-type` is meant to be used when the children can be of different types, and one want to target the last of one, which might not be the last child.

Comment: @LGSon does this mean that you don't have to mention what type the child will be when using `first-child` and `last-child`? Because yeah, that would be more correct. How would the CSS look for this?

Comment: As you use `p` all the time, `first/last-child` would be more appropriate than `first/last-of-type`. There is an answer with that, and I asked that user to undelete it. And if you mix different types, it will still pick the first/last, which `*-of-type` won't. And yes, you won't need to use a type.

Comment: @MikePierce Now that user undeleted their answer, but I also see that the accepted one changed theirs as well. IMHO, I would change accepted answer, since that one were the first to provide that solution.

Comment: @LGSON I changed my answer before disinfor undeleted his. So technically my answer still was the first one with `last-child`.

Comment: @imvain2 If you want to start with such discussion, _disinfor_ posted his answer a few minutes after yours, which were long before you changed yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:first-child` and `:last-child` accomplishes this no matter the number of children

```css
.proof p:first-child:before{
    content: "Proof. \00A0"; font-style: italic;
}

.proof p:last-child:after{
    content: "\2610"; float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="proof">
  <p>This paragraph will have an italic "Proof" before it.</p>
  <p>Whereas this paragraph will have a square after it.</p>
</div>

<div class="proof">
  <p>This paragraph will have an italic "Proof" before it and box after.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Posted the same answer, so removing mine and throwing you the upvote.

Comment: @disinfor I suggest you undelete yours, as it use `last-child`, which is more appropriate than `last-of-type`, which is suppose to be used for a different situation.

Answer (score 2):

Using your "ideal" markup, you could rely on `:first-child` and `:last-child`:

```css
.proof {display: block;}
.proof p:first-child::before {content: "Proof. \00A0"; font-style: italic;}
.proof p:last-child::after {content: "\2610"; float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="proof">
  <p>This paragraph will have an italic "Proof" before it.</p>
  <p>Whereas this paragraph will have a square after it.</p>
</div>
```